# how to make text able to copy in ionic App

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

i want to make a text able to copy in ionic App. i have tried this [How to allow copy and paste from an ionic webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893173/how-to-allow-copy-and-paste-from-an-ionic-webview) solution. but it didn't work for me. please could any suggestion me a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying these styles.

**In your CSS file:**

```
ion-content{
  overflow-scroll: true;
}

.scroll-content {
  -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
  -moz-user-select: auto !important;
  -ms-user-select: auto !important;
  user-select: auto !important;}

.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```

**In your Controller**

```
 stop_browser_behavior: false
  
self.touchStart = function(e) {
  self.startCoordinates = getPointerCoordinates(e);

  if ( ionic.tap.ignoreScrollStart(e) ) {
    return;
  }

  if( ionic.tap.containsOrIsTextInput(e.target) ) {
    // do not start if the target is a text input
    // if there is a touchmove on this input, then we can start the scroll
    self.__hasStarted = false;
    return;
  }

  self.__isSelectable = true;
  self.__enableScrollY = true;
  self.__hasStarted = true;
  self.doTouchStart(e.touches, e.timeStamp);
  // e.preventDefault();
};
```

**Then in your HTML:**

```
<div class='selectable'>
      This text should be selectable
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in .css file.

```
.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Have you set css class to .html file in appropriate tag?

Comment: how selectable will effect on html there is no class of this name in default css

Comment: means class="selectable" in your ionic webview. i m not telling about its default class.

Comment: i am not using webview

Comment: which control you are using for this functionality?

Comment: i am new in ionic so i didn't know to much about it.so you please tell me how can i implement it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151717/discussion-between-nilay-shah-and-suniel-kalwani).